# Can't use a Box in Amazon VPC subnet to connect to the other side of the site-to-site VPN tunnel which is already up

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, site-to-site-vpn, amazon-vpc, vyatta

This is what I have done

- created VPC 192.168.0.0/16
- created subnet 192.168.5.0/24
- created internet gateway
- attached internet gateway to VPC
- created routing table
- set destination route 0.0.0.0/0 to target the internet gateway
- associated routing table to subnet
- launched vyOS on EC2 using subnet with auto IP assigned (ICMP allowed)
- created elastic IP assigned to vyOS
- added second network interface eth1 auto IP 192.168.5.40 (default vpc secgroup)
- rebooted machine
- set ipsec ike and esp and preshared key with 2 tunnels. Both tunnels up
- ping from vyOS other side 10.2.0.20 got replies
- launced another box on same subnet with auto assigned IP with (default vpc secgroup with 22 and 80 allowed from 0.0.0.0/0 )

I have not been able to ping 10.2.0.20 from 192.168.5.40 but can from the vyOS box itself(with ip 192.168.5.17). I have added a new route on 192.168.5.40

```
sudo route add -net 10.2.0.0/24 gw 192.168.5.17
ubuntu@ip-192-168-5-40:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.2.0.20       192.168.5.17  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.5.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.5.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I know I am missing a point. NAT translation? Where is the catch? Can anybody points me to the right direction? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Common issue, make sure that you Disable Source/Destination Check on the instance ( right click -> Networking -> Change Source Dest. Check )

You'll only need to do this on the Vyos box.

You also don't really need a second interface. You could create a second subnet and on that route table for that subnet make the 0/0 route point to the Vyos instance if you want.